# Sending email notifications every 10 mins

Tags: compiler-errors, notifications

*com.plateausystems.elms.util.helper.ElmsNotifyException: An error occurred while sending scheduled mail  at com.plateausystems.elms.bo.apm.impl.ApmServiceImpl.sendScheduledMails(ApmServiceImpl.java:284)*

We have this automatic process where the system send email notification on a certain period or what ever time you set it up. Now the process sending email notifs every 10 mins. I checked the DB and that's the error I got. Now I dont know how can I stop it that scheduled mail?

Comment: I assume you're using a product published by [Success Factors](http://www.successfactors.com/homepage.html), which apparently acquired a company called Plateau Systems. You've given us very little to go on, but I think your best option right now would be to use [the publisher's own support tools](http://www.successfactors.com/support/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the source, debug and get the cause.
If not, you could maybe get to the code with cavaj and see in what circumstances the ElmsNotifyException will be thrown. Too bad you don't have the type of cause of the exception.

If the code used to work and now it broke down I would guess the problem is in the environment. Maybe the port used is no longer allowed, or credentials from the system are no longer known.

I would check and see what happend around the time it stopped working, like system upgrades. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you have no information other than, it broke.

So you could add additional logging at ApmServiceImpl.java in the sendScheduledMails method. Logging that actually captures the exception being thrown.

Once you know the exception(whats going wrong), you can fix it.